# Tapping Back button for closing Chrome always redirects to the same website

Tags: chrome-for-android, malware

Every time I want to close chrome with the back button I am redirected to same website. I want to get rid of this website but i cannot.

I cleared the browser history but the website keeps reappearing everytime I go back with backbutton before chrome is closed.

I have googled but could not find any solution to the problem. I ran multiple anti malware tools but none of them fixed it.

It is a particular website namely http://jamesclear.com/confirmed?__s=1bueuwtvop3g6ssfsutv which then redirects to jamesclear.com.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hover the `android` tab for important information

Comment: What do you mean by same website? Is the term 'same' in context of any website that you open, and when you tap back button you get redirected to that same website, or is it a particular website which is the cause of trouble?

Comment: It is a particular website namely http://jamesclear.com/confirmed?__s=1bueuwtvop3g6ssfsutv which then redirects to jamesclear.com.